# can't connect to DB codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to learn CodeIgniter by myself. but when I followed the specific instruction from this tutorial 
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

this is my DB config

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'test',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$db

Filename: pages/about.php

Line Number: 9

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CodeIgniter/application/views/pages/about.php
Line: 9
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CodeIgniter/application/controllers/Pages.php
Line: 18
Function: view

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CodeIgniter/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once


Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CodeIgniter/application/views/pages/about.php on line 9
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function query() on null

Filename: pages/about.php

Line Number: 9

Backtrace:
```

Comment: Have you already created your database with the credentials you have configured in codeigniter?

Comment: did you set these parameters ? `$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;`

Comment: @Alariva Yes the DB has been created

Comment: @PratikSoni yes those are there in the config DB file

Comment: I am not sure but you should try to set permission for config files to executable / readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking it is because you did not autoload the database library.

Path: **application/config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

As why `Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$db` shown.

Comment: @Keeper01 I think most common to autoload for helpers url, form, html and libraries database, sessions etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can try loading your model in controller or view using, recommendation is to load in controller...

`$this->load->model('News_model','News',true)`;

and then try to insert, update or delete using:

`$this->News->insert_function($param1,$param2);`

```
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function insert_function($param1,$param2)
    {
            $this->db->query("insert into table ('col1','col2') values ('$param1','$param2')");
            //other codes here....
    }
}
```

hope this help..